# Orbeon Forms - Sending Form Edit URL to Rest Service

Tags: forms, url, edit, orbeon

I have a need to send the URL for editing a specific form to a REST service when `save` button of my form is clicked. Currently that URL is displayed as a part of `success-message`. See my property in `properties-local-pord.xml` file:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save.VIRGINAUSI.*"
    value='
        require-uploads
        then require-valid
        then save
        then success-message(
            message="Form has been saved as : http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/VIRGINAUSI/VARADemo/edit/{/form/sec1/docID}"
        )
        recover error-message("database-error")
    '/>
```

Now I need to send this URL once the `save` button is clicked without displaying it as a part of `success-message`.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`send()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner-send.html) to call your service as part of the process, passing the URL in a way similar to what you are doing with `success-message()`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I have `send()` action for another button. The code for it is as below `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.VIRGINAUSI.*"
value="http://localhost:8080/OrbeonRouter/rest/xml"/>
<property as="xs:string" 
 name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.VIRGINAUSI.*"
 value='require-valid
 then save-final
 then send("oxf.fr.detail.send.success", content="xml", replace="none")
 then navigate("http://localhost:8080/email-sent-virgin-ausi.html")
 recover navigate("http://localhost:8080/email-fail-virgin-ausi.html")'/>` Do you mean that I can do the same for `save()` button too?

Comment: In that case how can I pass parameters like App Name(`VIRGINAUSI`) , form name (`VARADemo`) and document ID to the service?

Comment: First, I would really recommend you put the code for your process inside the element, [like so](https://gist.github.com/avernet/ffbe41039a97e043a9434b3d7679d269), instead of having it in the `value` attribute. This way you can indent it more easily to make it readable, and don't have to escape the single quote. And you can also see in that example how I am passing to the service the value of a field named `first-name`, inside a section named `personal-info`. Is this inline with what you're looking for?

Comment: Just wondering: did you manage to pass a field value as a request parameter when calling your service with `send()`?

Comment: Sorry @avernet for the delay of response. I could not try this one as the task was put on hold. However it will be resumed soon. Will update you. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the update, and of course feel free to comment here when/if you get a chance to get back to this one. And Happy New Year!

Comment: Sure, will update you once it is done. Wishing you A Happy New Year 2018! @avernet